# ActiveRecord query with OR and where.not

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following queries that work separately, but I haven't been able to make one query out of it, and I'm not sure what the SQL approach would be.

Any recommendations?

```
Discussion.joins(:discussion_tags).where.not(discussion_tags: { taggable_type: 'Product'})
Discussion.includes(:discussion_tags).where(discussion_tags: { id: nil})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Discussion.includes(:discussion_tags).where('discussion_tags.taggable_id IS NULL or  discussion_tags.taggable_type != ?', 'Product').references(:discussion_tags)`

Comment: Thanks AbM! the only thing this needed was .references(:discussion_tags) at the end, and it worked!